# How to run reposync with a different releaseversion value

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, reprepro

I want to make a CentOS mirror with different versions of CentOS? How do I do that with reposync. I can't use rsync.

Comment: I can't point to anything official yet, but since ["reposync uses the yum libraries for retrieving information and packages ... yum configuration will be used"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reposync), it would seem ... tricky ... to me to have repos on your system for multiple versions of the OS.

Comment: I considered changing `releasever`. In some config file and changing it back before using yum again. But there doesn't seem to be any way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an easy way now with `dnf --releasever=...`

So on Rocky8 you can create Rocky9 repo easily: Download key, import key, create local repo:

```shell
curl -LO 'https://dl.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/RPM-GPG-KEY-Rocky-9'
rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-Rocky-9
dnf --releasever=9 reposync -g --delete -p /storage/repos/9/ --repoid=extras --download-metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the Yum configuration files from a machine running the CentOS distribution you want to mirror, then change `$releasever` to hardcode the version you want. Then you can use the `-c` option to reposync to tell it to use your copied configuration file instead of the system one.

For example, to mirror the latest CentOS 7 version on a CentOS 8 machine, copy `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and change `$releasever` in that file to `7`. Then you can run:

`reposync -c CentOS-Base.repo`

Adding any additional desired options (for example, --repoid if you don't want to sync all the enabled repositories in that file). Similarly, you can copy and make similar changes to any additional repositories you want, such as epel.repo.